# Can't use redis-cli within a docker container that has redis installed

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, containers, redis-cli

I am working on a Python-Flask project that has two separate docker containers for the web app and the postgres database.  I want to start using rq and redis with the web app, so I added a docker container that holds the redis server.  When I tried to ping the redis container from the web app container, I wasn't able to use `redis-cli`.  Redis is installed in the web app container.  Why can't I use `redis-cli` from the web app container?

When I ping the redis server from within the redis container, the response indicates that the server is up.

```sh
docker exec -it MyApp_redis_1 redis-cli ping
PONG
```

But, when I attempt to ping the redis server from within the web app container, I can't even use redis-cli.  I ran `pip freeze` within the web container and confirmed that `redis==3.2.1` is installed.  Still, I get the below error message

```sh
docker exec -it MyApp_web_1 redis-cli ping
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"redis-cli\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I also get an error message when I attempt to use `redis-cli` from a shell in the web app container:

```sh
/usr/src/app/MyApp$ redis-cli ping
bash: redis-cli: command not found
```

Why can't I use redis-cli from within a docker container that has redis installed?

Here is an excerpt from my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
 redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:5.0.5
  command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
  hostname: redis

 web:
   restart: always
   build:
      context: .
      args:
      - DOCKER_BUILD_ENV
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/web/Dockerfile
   environment:
     ****variables that I won't put on StackOverflow****
   volumes:
     - ./MyApp/:/usr/src/app/MyApp/:z
   links:
     - postgres:postgres
     - redis:redis
   expose:
     - "3000"
   command: scripts/entrypoint.sh
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
```

Thanks for reading!  (If needed, I can also share my Dockerfile.)

Comment: The message is clear, you don't have redis-cli installed in your web container. If you think you have it installed, post your Dockerfile or try building your image again.

Comment: Far as I know simply installing a Redis client library doesn't mean that "redis" or "redis-cli" utility will be installed. The Python library is simply a means of communicating with an existing/running Redis installation. You either need to install "redis" or just "redis-cli" into your web app container, or to just run your ping command through a Python shell with the redis module imported.